# How can I position images in four corners to collectively form a circle?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make this specific design in CSS but I couldn't figure out a way to do it .

[image]

The code I tried didn't give me the result and I don't know what I'm doing wrong .

The images I got are already rounded corners so I just need to place them in the corners of rectangles so I can add some text later on.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.rectangle img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(1) img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(2) img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(3) img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(4) img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle">
      <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle">
      <img src="image4.jpg" alt="Image 4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for position:relative? Absolute coordinates are for the whole document. Edit: you could also try using percentages in the position, like -50%. Maybe try defining the width and height of the image as well?

Comment: I'd make them background images and position backgrounds. Also your snippet doesn't work because there are no images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons why you are not getting the intended result:

- `<div class="container">` uses flexbox so the two child `<div class="row">` are positioned horizontally side-by-side. `<div class="rectangle">` is block level and is positioned vertically above/below each other. Therefore, what you intended to be rows are actually columns.
- Your `:nth-child(3)` and `:nth-child(4)` selectors don't match anything because there are only two `<div class="rectangle">` child elements of each `<div class="row">` (you could have used `:nth-of-type()`)
- `.rectangle {flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px)}` has no effect because `<div class="row">` is not a flex container
- After removing the `<div class="row">` containers, another apparent issue is the images cover the entire `div` due to these declarations that should be removed:

```css
.rectangle img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

We get the desired positioning after making those corrections:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.rectangle img {
  position: absolute;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(1) img {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(2) img {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(3) img {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(4) img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?1" alt="Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?2" alt="Image 2">
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?3" alt="Image 3">
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?4" alt="Image 4">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, now you'll discover that the images are placed on top of other content. The images should be used as the background image for this effect.

```css
.rectangle {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?1);
  background-position: bottom 0 right 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?2);
  background-position: bottom 0 left 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?3);
  background-position: top 0 right 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?4);
  background-position: top 0 left 0;
}
```

To fix the double margin around the flex items, declare `gap` and `padding` on the container and adjust the `flex-basis` calculation.

```css
.container {
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.rectangle {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.rectangle {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?1);
  background-position: bottom 0 right 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?2);
  background-position: bottom 0 left 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?3);
  background-position: top 0 right 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?4);
  background-position: top 0 left 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regarding your comment about using components: I don't have any knowledge of using components. Would it be possible to declare the value for `background-image: url()` in a `<style>` block on the page?

```html
<style>
  .rectangle:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?1);
  }

  .rectangle:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?2);
  }

  .rectangle:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?3);
  }

  .rectangle:nth-child(4) {
    background-image: url(//picsum.photos/100?4);
  }
</style>
```

If you must use `<img>`, this can be done using the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property. (This will require all text in `<div class="rectangle">` to be inside child elements.) Using `z-index` for this result can potentially conflict with other elements on the page (present or future) that also use `z-index`.

```css
.rectangle > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rectangle img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.rectangle > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rectangle img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(1) img {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(2) img {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(3) img {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rectangle:nth-child(4) img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?1" alt="Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?2" alt="Image 2">
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?3" alt="Image 3">
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p><cite>Lorem ipsum</cite> is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/100?4" alt="Image 4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well this is actually what I'm looking for . Just one last question , how can I add the images from HTML because I'm creating components so adding the pictures in CSS wouldn't be the best solution. Thank you.

Comment: I've added a third demo for using `<img>` with the `z-index` property

Answer (score -1):

You could use these css properties:

```
border-top-left-radius: 100%; /* for the top left image */
border-top-right-radius: 100%; /* for the top right image */
border-bottom-right-radius: 100%; /*for the bottom right image */
border-bottom-left-radius: 100%; /* for the bottom left image*/
```